# why would Matlab skip the loop?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, loops, matlab-guide

I have a question that I can seem to wrap my head around,

I have created a gui that uses the unput from the user to run a script within the gui and later display the results to the user interface. What I dont understand is that everything is running ok until I choose one particular file. The interesting and mind boggling is that the script jumps a nested loop (whie this dosent happen for the other choices). I dont understand why this happens and cant find anything relavent on the internet. The script stand alone executes perfectly.

```
for i=2:length(Data_last_values)
       for j=2:length(temp_nov)
           if Data_last_values(i,4)>temp_nov(j,1) & Data_last_values(i,4)<temp_nov(j-1,1)
                Data_last_values(i,9)=Data_last_values(i,3)+Q_leak_dot(j);
                disp('gone through loop')
           end
       end      
      end
```

displayed above is the part of the nested loop that matlab chooses to skip. would any one know why this happens? below I present the gui script:

```
if not(isempty(cell2mat(z)))
run Daughter
assignin('base','avg',data(:,8))
    axes(handles.axes1);
    markerSize = 50;
    scatter(Data_last_values(:,4),Data_last_values(:,9),markerSize,Data_last_values(:,5))  % -> volumetric mass flow is used in the color bar
    colormap(jet(20));
    h=colorbar;
    xlabel('T_{water}[C]')
    ylabel('Q_{out} [W]')
    ylabel(h, 'Volumetric Flow [Lt/min]')
    grid minor
    myvar = evalin('base', 'avg');
    y=line([0 max(Data_last_values(:,4))], [mean(myvar) mean(myvar)]);
    xlim([0 max(Data_last_values(:,4))])
```

Comment: What value does `length(Data_last_values)` has, in that specific moment?

Comment: MATLAB does not simply 'skip' a loop. I think, as @AnderBiguri suggests, that your variable `Data_last_values` has zero or one length and therefore does not execute.

Comment: It might be that your `if clause` is not satisfied. Or the loops are never entered because eigther `length(temp_nov) = 1` or  `length(Data_last_values) = 1`.

Comment: hey guys thank you for your input, it turned out that i had a terible logical error in my if statement... it turned out that ata_last_values spaned from 40-56 while the temp_nov from 59 to 60, so the comdition was never met...